# Как передать Drawable через Intent

Tags: android

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyClass.class);
Drawable drawable= mMyImageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();// string №3
intent.putExtra("bitmap", bitmap);
startActivity(intent);
```

Подобное преобразование Drawable -> Bitmap встретил в нескольких интернет-рессурсах, но в строке 3 выдетает java.lang.ClassCastException если формат drawable SVG! (с png проблем не возникает). Но я работаю с SVG...

Comment: Передавайте файлы, а не drawable

Comment: ok, сейчас попробую реализовать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать. Но. Никогда так не делайте. через данные в intent Extras копируются а не передаются по ссылке, соответственно, если у вас пускай даже не большая картинка, он будет делать её копию, и это займет время плюс память.  Что потенциально приведет к OutOfMemorryError в рантайме. Вариантов тут несколько,

1. Не красивый - завести в MyClass статичесое поле с сеттером и класть туда картинку перед запуском активити. По большому счету кроме отсутствия копирования и слегка грязноватого кода, отличия от intent.putExtra не будет.
2. Завести отдельный класс (возможно Singleton, и HashMap внутри ) где будут лежать картинки и прочие данные которые вам нужны между Активити фрагментами и прочим. Ну и в активити через интент уже передавать стрингу с названием файла.
3. Ну ладно в самом крайнем случае, файл можно всегда превратить в байты и передать как массив... Но как говорится... Пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живёте.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение. Если Вы будете передавать через intent данные размером больше 1МБ, то получите TransactionTooLargeException. С битмапами превысить порог в 1МБ проще простого. Вообще лучше никогда не передавать большие объекты через Intent.